# get facebook user session after it over

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbjs

I am using facebook connect and authenticate the user with it.

For each user, there is session key that expire after X minutes. How can I get the user session after the session is over ?

I tried-

```
FB.Connect.requireSession();
```

but I don't want to use this function because it pops up the facebook connect 
username and password. I want to get the user session without him to reenter his username and password/ and I dont want to ask for infinity session.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prompt for extended permissions with offline access. When this is completed facebook gives you a special infinite session key which you need to save and use when you want to act on that user's behalf.

```
FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("offline_access", function(result){ 
   //callback function when users accepts extended permissions
});
```

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/JS_API_M_FB.Connect.ShowPermissionDialog